# Docker-machine host env on multiple computers?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using `docker-machine` to create a box on a digitalocean droplet.   I have deployed a simple hello world docker container to that host and it works fine.

When I do a `docker-machine ls` on my main computer I see the digitalocean driver running like a champ.

I now want to be able to move to my laptop and do a `docker-machine ls` and see the digital ocean driver running there too, but am unclear as to how to "share" the machine so its accessible from two different computers.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's looking like if I just copy the `~/.docker/machines/{machine}` from one machine to the other it will "work" or am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: Yes that's how it works. Suck it and see :-)   You'll discover that the ~/.docker/machine directory contains all the SSL keys created to secure communication between you (the workstation) and the remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm package https://github.com/bhurlow/machine-share#readme. It provides the missing import/export functionality in docker machine

Comment: once I've used `machine-import` on the remote machine, I run `docker-machine ls` and I still see nothing, is there an extra step involved in actually connecting to the containers?